# Like operator in jsp

Tags: html, sql, jsp

I want to display  search result in jsp page. I used like operator for searching, but I did not get true result.

```
st =conn.prepareStatement("select * from books where  book_name like ?  ");
        st.setString(1, "%"+book+"%");

        ResultSet rslt = st.executeQuery();

if(rslt.next()){   %>
<h3  align="center">Result Of Your Search  </h3>
<table align="center">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td>Book Name</td>

 </thead>

    <tbody>
  <% while(rslt.next()){ %>
   <tr>
    <td><%=rslt.getString("book_name")%></td>
```

When I wrote Java in search box I got only this result: `Head First Java, 2nd Edition`, but I have another book in database with name "Java: Graphical User Interfaces"

Why I cant get true result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change if condition. You're starting the cycle with using it.

Or You can use this or in any other way;

```
if(rslt.next()) { 
  do { 

  } while (rslt.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling next() two times before displaying the results:

```
if (rslt.next()) {
   // so now, you point at the first result

   while (rslt.next()) {
       // so now, you point at the second result
```